# Teradata SQL Assistant - Practice database

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm new to Teradata SQL Assistant and I need to use it for work.

I've been looking for some example database to do some practice on but is quite lost. Can somebody provide guideline and help to use a sample database available on the web?

Answer (score 1):

You can download [Teradata Express for VMware Player](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/database/teradata-express-for-vmware-player) from Teradata Downloads which will allow you to run Teradata in a virtual machine on your desktop. Alternatively, you can also use a free trial of [Teradata on AWS Marketplace](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/database/teradata-express/amazon-ec2).